# How to forward logs from syslog-ng to journald?

Tags: syslog-ng, journald

journald does everything I need except listen on the UDP port. I want to use syslog-ng as a forwarder from the UDP port to journald. There's a simple program called 'udp514-journal' that can handle this. However, syslog-ng seems more reliable and functionally capable (with TLS encryption and filters). There are many examples of how to forward logs from journald to syslog-ng, but I'm trying to achieve the opposite. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option that I have found is to use a `/dev/log`

but not as unix socket but as unix datagram

```
@version: 4.4

options {
  stats(freq(1));
  flush_lines (0);
  time_reopen (10);
  log_fifo_size (10000);
  chain_hostnames (off);
  dns_cache (no);
  use_dns (no);
  use_fqdn (no);
  create_dirs (no);
  keep_hostname (yes);
  perm(0640);
  group("log");
};

source network_input_udp_514 {
  udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};

destination journalctl {
  unix-dgram("/dev/log");
};

log {
  source(network_input_udp_514);
  destination(journalctl);
};
```

seems to be working just fine for me - all messages are in

```
journalctl -u syslog-ng@default.service
```